# Can we access resolved parameters from template returning function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state like this

```
                .state('dropdown', {
                    url: '/dropdown',
                    views: {
                        "@":{
                            template: getTemplate(params)
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: {
                        params: function(){
                            return {
                                stateHeader: 'Dropdown',
                                moduleName: 'dropdown',
                                files: [{"title": "dropdown.html", "path":"app/modules/dropdown/dropdown.html"}, {"title": "dropdown.ctrl.js", "path":"app/modules/dropdown/dropdown.ctrl.js"}, {"title": "dropdown.css", "path":"app/modules/dropdown/dropdown.css"}]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
```

and the template returning function is

```
function getTemplate(stateParams) {

    // I want to access those resolved parameters here

    var moduleName = stateParams.moduleName;
    var templateUrl = moduleName + '/' + moduleName;
    return '<div><tabs-directive exe-template=\'app/modules/' + templateUrl + '.html\' files=\'' + stateParams.files + '\' header=\'Basic Usage\'></tabs-directive></div>';
}
```

How can I pass and access those resolved params object in the getTemplate function to return the template using the same function? Please help me.

**Note:** getTemplate function must be re-used for other states also.

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('dropdown', {
  url: '/dropdown',
  params: {
    stateHeader: 'Dropdown',
    moduleName: 'dropdown',
    files: [
      {"title": "dropdown.html", "path":"app/modules/dropdown/dropdown.html"},
      {"title": "dropdown.ctrl.js", "path":"app/modules/dropdown/dropdown.ctrl.js"},
      {"title": "dropdown.css", "path":"app/modules/dropdown/dropdown.css"}
    ]
  },
  views: {
    "@": {
      template: getTemplate($stateParams) {
        var moduleName = $stateParams.moduleName;
        var templateUrl = moduleName + '/' + moduleName;
        console.log('<div><tabs-directive exe-template=\'app/modules/' + templateUrl + '.html\' files=\'' + $stateParams.files + '\' header=\'Basic Usage\'></tabs-directive></div>');
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Nothing is 'resolved' in your code, they appear to all be params, so you don't need the resolve at all. When you refer to the params, even though they're in the same 'state', you still need to look at it as $stateParams (not stateParams), so the getTemplate() should use that as arguments not params.

Comment: I want to re-use that function